# Error: can't dereference value-initialized vector iterator

Tags: c++

Error: can't dereference value-initialized vector iterator

when i am trying  to deference an iterator

```
/*
* e.g. ["1","2","3"] will produce => [ ["1","2","3"], ["2","3","1"], ["3","1","2"],]
*/
vector<vector<string>> getRotation(vector<string> in) {

    size_t num_rotation = in.size() - 1;

    vector<string> variantion(in);
    vector<vector<string>> result{ in };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_rotation; i++)
    {
        vector<string>::iterator temp = variantion.begin();
        string tempValue = *temp; // Error: can't dereference value-initialized vector iterator

        // variantion remove the first element ,and append to the end
        variantion.erase(temp);
        variantion.push_back(tempValue);

        result.push_back(variantion);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `variantion`, which is just a copy of `in`. `in` is already a copy of the caller's input `vector`, so you can just mutate `in` directly.

Comment: thanks for the teaching!!!

Answer (score -1):

it end out my parameter in has size of 0, so this code return me a null iterator

```
        vector<string>::iterator temp = variantion.begin();
```

i think that is why it throw error.

Comment: Your `num_rotation` will also be a VERY large number when `in` is empty. `size_t` is an unsigned type, and subtracting `-1` from an unsigned type when it is 0 will wrap to the largest value that the type can hold.